# Web service to insert and view database data

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services, elasticsearch

I need a web-service which allows admins to insert new data and viewers to see this data-tables. Therefore at first i need a database (Mysql ?). Is a mySql db on a server the right choice? Afterwards a website should be connected to this db, where users can see specific tables and admins can add new lines into this tables. Finally this tables should be able to only show the last xy-lines of the respective table.

Use-case: I have a **restaurant**, and when I get orders, i want to provide a simple table where the telephone-workers can add new orders (e.g. 3x pizza salami); afterwards this table is opened with view-rights on a display in the kitchen. So the chefs can create the orders.

Which database is the optimal here?
What kind of web-service is the right and how is this connected and set up?

Comment: Write code, get stuck and come back here for assistance

Comment: There’s no one answer. You could try looking at the tags here and seeing which options are most popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL or SQL Server. And you can use Web Pages instead of web-service.